# Webmethod raises "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member..."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asmx, webmethod, pagemethods

I have the following webmethod

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> Public Shared Function NewMethod(ByVal str1 As String) As String
  LoadBlock(str1)
  Return "Success"
End Function
```

and the following procedure

```
Public Sub LoadBlock(ByVal AA As Integer)
  panAway.Visible = False '<--ASP panel control
  lblHome.Visible = False '<--ASP label control
End
```

Which raises the following error

```
Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or 
shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.
```

I understand that i am getting the following error because i have not set the LoadBlock as Shared

But if i do that all the controls within my procedure... raise the error above

Is there anything i can do about that?

Comment: FYI, the `WebMethod` isn't "raising" an error - that's a simple compiler error, and already tells you what you need to know - assuming you know what "instance method" and "shared method" mean.

Answer (score 5):

A "Page Method" is always a `Shared` (`static` in C#) method. It can never reference the controls on your page, nor any other instance data or methods.

In fact, keep in mind that, in ASP.NET, an instance of your page only exists during each HTTP request. The request to your WebMethod is a separate request - there is no instance of a page that it could possibly refer to. The instance has been destroyed by the time the request to the WebMethod arrives.

Comment: Which means i locked the drawer and put the key inside? :-) The webmethod is called by an ajax postback... but now it seems i have another problem :-(